# how to plot some lists with different shape?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some lists that each of which has a different shape and I would like to plot all of them together in one polar scatter plot. I also tried to use `iter tools` but I could not find the solution.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
a2=[2,3,5,6]
a3=[1,2,3]
a4=[1,2,3,4,4,56,7,8]
ax1 = plt.subplot(111,polar= True)
for i in range (0,3):
   theta = 4 * np.pi * np.random.rand(len(a[i]))
ax1.set_ylim(0,0.1)
ax1.set_rlabel_position(180)
for i in range (0,3):
    ax1.scatter(theta,a[i], cmap='hsv', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: `theta` is defined in your first for-loop and used in the second, that will not run.

Comment: @funie200 Yes, true. How can I make it? I mean how to plot altogether. When in every list, we have a different shape, in every session of plotting it needs to have the same axis in x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull i modified your lists for a better visual exmaple!
I hope I understood your question correctly...

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
a2=[2,3,5,6]
a3=[1,2,3]
a4=[1,2,3,4,4,7,7,8]
ax1 = plt.subplot(111,polar= True)

    
for onelist in [a1,a2,a3,a4]:
    theta_list = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,len(onelist))
    ax1.plot(theta_list,onelist,marker="x")
    
plt.show()
```

[image]